# What Am I? - Vowels #2

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> With an a, I'm a noise
>   With an e, I'm hatching
>   With an i, I'm an action
>   With an o, I can measure
>   With a u, I'm the sound of a bird

What am I?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the results of [this search](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=vowelburger) on PSE...

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No need to stick to Avi's brand though, if Dooper has had the same essential puzzle idea independently.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I did not take anyone's idea on purpose. I will try to start a different series if that is what you want.

Comment: I didn't mean any sort of accusation! I just thought you might be amused.

Comment: Oh! Well, in that case, sorry about that.

Comment: I was amused by the same exact thing. @Dooper, you've just missed a whole Vowelburger chain war. Or something like that

Comment: Is the last clue fair? I would not say that rot13(n pyhpx vf n oveq).

Comment: @LannyStrack I fixed it. Thanks for catching that one!

Comment: I was trying to think of birds with "u" in their name, like thrush or duck :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Sorry! I'll try to be more careful in the future. Thanks again for pointing it out!

Comment: I've posted [another one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/95073/5373) in your style. I like this way better than the Vowelburgers thing actually - it's more natural and less stylised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> CL-CK

making

> CLACK, a noise; CLECK, which indeed means to hatch (an obscure word indeed); CLICK, an action that you might take while using your computer; CLOCK, which measures time; and CLUCK, which some birds do.

Comment: Correct! People here are very fast at answering!