# With different vowels, what am I?

Tags: riddle, word, letters

> With an A, I might be a programming trick.
>   With an E, I'm really not sure.
>   With an I, I'm just a wee babe.
>   With an O, I'm often stopping.
>   With a U, I'm a guy you can meet.

What am I?

Comment: Boringifying the vowelburger meme?

Comment: @Bass I prefer a natural, classical style to something stylised and "trademarked". Nobody owns the idea of a puzzle where different vowels go between the same consonants.

Comment: Hmm.  Is there a word or letter sequence where most consonants can be exchanged. I know J,Q,X and Z might be very hard but others?

Comment: @DEEM Dunno about *most* consonants, but you can make a puzzle with [just a few](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/94716/5373).

Comment: @Randal'Thor I realised that you almost never mark an answer a correct before. Is there a reason for it?

Comment: @UnidentifiedX I've marked [210 answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A5373+is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3A1) as correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are:

> The letter sequence **CHxCK**.

*With an A, I might be a programming trick.*

> **CHACK** - or rather, **C HACK**: what you might term a shortcut in the programming language 'C'.

*With an E, I'm really not sure.*

> Well, if you're not sure then go and **CHECK**!

*With an I, I'm just a wee babe.*

> A baby bird is a **CHICK**.

*With an O, I'm often stopping.*

> A **CHOCK** is a wedge or block used to stop a wheel from rolling.

*With a U, I'm a guy you can meet.*

> **CHUCK** is a male name.

Comment: Well done. Too easy?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - As these kinds of riddles go: no, it wasn't an instant solve :) Just happened to be perusing the site when the puzzle popped up. Once I found I and O it seemed my idea had potential, but coming up against A gave me a few minutes' doubt before thinking my way around it!

Comment: Thinking your way around it ... one might say you found a hack to make it work.